# Hough transform to detect shape using equation of that shape

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform, polynomials, shape-recognition

Is it possible to implement Hough Transform to detect shape (given in the form of equation). I know there is a generalized Hough transform to which we need to pass an image and a template but is there any way to pass equation of shape instead of template.

Comment: Make a template from the equation?

Comment: @AnderBiguri how?

Comment: If you have the equation, simply determine which are the parameters (make sure it's not more than 3 or 4, otherwise your parameter space will be unmanageable). 1- Iterate over those parameters. 2- Sample the image at the locations given by your shape equation for those parameters. 3- Add the those pixel values. 4- Write them to the bin for those parameters. 5- Repeat for all other parameter combinations.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sir equation could vary it is not fixed.

Comment: What do you mean not fixed? You have an equation with several parameters, yes? It doesn't randomly change half-way the analysis, I hope?